# solution-verification | Prove that the triangles $AMD'$ and $ACB'$ have the same center of gravity.

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

**the question**

Let the cube $ABCDA'B'C'D'$ and $M$ be a point on the semi-right $(AB$ so that $BM=AB$. Prove that the triangles $AMD'$ and $ACB'$ have the same center of gravity.

**the drawing**

[image]

**the idea**

In traingle $AMD'$, B is the midpoint of MA, which means that $D'B$ is a median and the center of gravity of that traingle (let it be $G_1$) verify this relation $G_1B=\frac{D'B}{3}$

Let $DB$ intersect $AC$ in point $O$ => O is the midpoint of BD and AC

In triangle $ACB'$, O is the midpoint of ac, which means that $B'O$ is a median and the centre of gravity of that traingle (let it be $G_2$) verify this relation $G_2O=\frac{B'O}{3}$

Let the inetrsection of lines $D'B, B'O$ be $G$

$D'B' || OB =>$ triangles $D'B'G$ and $BOG$ are similar and have the report of similarity $2$, which means $GB=\frac{D'B}{3}$ and $GO=\frac{OB'}{3}$

This means that $G_1, G_2$ and $G$ are the same points and we arrive to the desire conclusion.

Im not sure if showing these reports means that the points coincide, but that's why i posted this question.

Hope one of you can tell me if my rationament is right or not. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct and perfect, bravo! The strategy to invoke a third intermediate point $G$ which is shown to coincide with both the concerned centroids works out well.

The reason your conclusion of points in same ratio implying coincidence holds is because you first show that the points $G_1$ and $G$ lie on the same line ($D'B$), then show that their distance from a fixed point ($B$) is the same (since length of $D'B$ is fixed) and on the same side of B (obviously), meaning the points must be coincident. You can think of this like a circle of fixed radius can cut a ray passing through the centre at exactly one point.

This proves $G_1 = G$. By identical logic, $G_2 = G$ and hence by transitivity, $G_1 = G_2$ and you're done.

Having said this, I feel it's important to suggest a couple of tangible improvements, the first being vocabulary. Mathematics already is an intricate subject and there's simply no need to add to that by using non-standard terms such as centre of gravity or report, which could perhaps throw people off.

There's nothing called as centre of gravity in Mathematics. You can occasionally use it to gain intuitive insight in certain problems but that's about it - it is NOT a substitute for the term **centroid**, which is standard and accepted. For triangles especially please stick to that. Furthermore, I don't think the term "report" is used to refer to similarity, a simple "ratio" of similarity would suffice.

A more important suggestion, your geometric approach here is nice to the eye but not generalisable, *i.e.* if there's a new problem of this kind you'll have to perform your entire analysis again. That can easily be avoided by developing one robust algorithm to address all such problems instead. To that end, I propose the use of coordinate geometry.

Label the cube along the unit cubicle - A(0,0,0), B(1,0,0), C(1,1,0), D(0,1,0) and the other four vertices right above these. Then, since AB = BM, we get $m = 2b - a = (2,0,0)$. Now simply compute the averages of the coordinates of A,M,D' and A,C,B' and you'll be done, since the centroid of triangle XYZ is given by $\frac{x+y+z}{3}$.

Hope this helps. I'll leave it to you to figure out why this method is easier to scale than the one you've used.

Comment: @TejasGShende Thank you for your suggestion, Im not that fluent in English, so in some parts of the post I used a translator, this being the cause of the wrong forms...

Comment: @Tejas_GS25 there is long tradition of solving geometric problems by appealing to centers of mass (or gravity), though it's also true we tend to use the term centroid these days. For example, the volume of a sphere was first found via centers of gravity, by Archimedes.

Comment: @RobinSparrow I agree, mechanics in general has played a key role in the development of a lot of mathematics (such as calculus) but it is nonetheless redundant and inappropriate to use antiquated terms in a formal answer, I feel.